# Add reference of one CSharp project to another CSharp proejct using Cmake and build using MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, cmake, csproj

I am new to Cmake and MSBuild. I have gone through multiple posts that talk about linking libraries in Cmake. One or two do talk about linking projects, but they are mostly about C++ projects. My question is specific to adding reference of one C# project to another C# project, where both the projects are generated using CMake and are part of the same .Net solution, and building the projects, using MSBuild, successfully after generation.
I have two C# projects generated using cmake. Current folder structure of Projects is:

ProjA

---cmake.txt

---projA.csproj.template

ProjB

---Cmake.txt

---projB.csproj.template

Cmake uses cmake.txt for the projects which in turn uses csproj file to generate C# projects ProjectA and Project B. Fyi, the *.cs files for C# projects are generated using Swig. I am not going into the details of it as the *.cs files generated are correct.

Project B has types that are required in Project A. Hence we want to add reference of project B into Project A.

In order to do that I first tried adding reference of Project B into ProjectA csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\FolderB\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj">
    <Project>{PROJ GUID}</Project>
      <Name>ProjectB</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I tested the changes by opening the cmake generated .Net solution and building it manually. The changes built fine. But when I use cmake to generate these projects and then using MSbuild build the .Net solution and the projects, the build fails.
Build error (for Project A) which I get are:

The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I open the generated C# Project and build it individually the projects build just fine without any build errors.

By reading the error it seems that Cmake is still unable to add a reference of Project B to Project A. So, next in addition to added reference of Project B in ProjectA csproj file, I tried adding reference of ProjectB in CMake.txt of Project A. I did this by adding command `target_link_libraries(ProjectAName "ProjectBName")` to cmake.txt file.

Another thing which I tried was that adding reference to Project A via include_external_msproject command (in cmake.txt) i.e.:

```
include_external_msproject(
  ProjectAName 
  ${csprojfileName}
  TYPE "${CS_GUID}"
  ProjectB
)
```

The build still failed.

Let me know if there was any issue with these tries and what further changes can be made so that CMake generates correct information for Project A so that at build time MSBuild is aware that Project A has reference of Project B.

Comment: is the project Guid inside the `<ProjectReference>` the one of project b? (the referenced one)

Comment: @MartinUllrich yes the project GUID inside the <ProjectReference> is of ProjectB. I have verified that. Another thing is that when I open the whole .Net solution and build the project individually, they will build fine. So that is another indicator that things are configured correctly.